# How to Order div content for SEO

Tags: css, seo

I really want my navigation code to fall below my content code for SEO purposes. But I have a layout where the navigation div is floated up and to the left of the main body content. This means the content sits beneath the nav div and wraps around the right side and the bottom of the nav div. As such, I've conceded that the nav div must be nested inside the content div. Hence, the nav div code always ends up above my content which is poor for SEO results. I've tried several different options to switch the content and the nav div around but to no avail. I've tried floats, position relative/absolute, negative margins, etc. to achieve the desired effect. None produce the desired effect and preserve the layout (particularly the margins around the nav div between the nav and the body content).

Any suggestions would sure be appreciated.

Page is at:
http://www.netcentric-tech.com/customer/test/2nd-test.shtml

CSS:
http://www.netcentric-tech.com/customer/test/css/custom-test.css

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: Pleas read this. No one want to reverse-engineer your web site. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First... Honestly, I wouldn't worry about your navigation "getting in the way" of the search engines. There's not a lot of markup there and the SEs are rather efficient. If you really wanted to, though, you could put the navigation within the content section (at the end) and give it position: absolute; with some negative margins for positioning. This will work as long as it's parent container (the content) has position: relative; applied.

Comment: I tried the position absolute method earlier using both positioning and negative margins but it left undesirable spacing between the nav area and the content area. To compensate, I then applied a negative margin to the content but it negatively affected the margins of the text content below the nav div.